# Как предотвратить создание клонов объекта в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Суть следующая. У меня есть шарик. Передвижение осуществляется при помощи мыши. Если его коллайдер сталкивается с любым другим коллайдером, то объект уничтожается. И создаётся новый объект в точке респауна. Когда столкновение происходит одновременно с несколькими коллайдерами, то создаётся несколько объектов. А должен один.
Каким образом можно ограничить количество клонов, либо выполнять проверку на наличие клонов и уничтожать их?

Собственно код.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _player;
    public Transform _startPosition;
    private Vector2 _distance;
    private float _playerPosX;
    private float _playerPosY;
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _distance = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        _playerPosX = Input.mousePosition.x - _distance.x;
        _playerPosY = Input.mousePosition.y - _distance.y;
    }
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector2 _currentPosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x - _playerPosX, Input.mousePosition.y - _playerPosY);
        Vector2 _worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(_currentPosition);
        _player.transform.position = _worldPosition;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals("Hardles"))
        {
            ReInstantiatePlayer();
            Debug.Log("TAG is HARDLES");
        }
        Debug.Log("Collizion enter");
    }
    private void ReInstantiatePlayer()
    {
        Instantiate(_player, _startPosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(_player, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: У "клонируемого" объекта храните булевую переменную (допустим isDead). По умолчанию она равна false. При столкновении Вы проверяете, если столкнулся с "правильным" объектом и isDead == false ------------> выставляете флаг isDead в true и выполняете метод ReInstantiatePlayer

Comment: так же можно использовать ннкий таймаут

Comment: А вот мысль с булевой переменной мне не пришла в голову.
Сейчас проверю.

Comment: Попробовал с булевой _isDead, при одновременном столкновением с тремя коллайдерами всё равно происходит клонирование. А каким образом образом перестать считывать мышь?

Comment: У вас очень странная логика передвижения шара с переводом мировых координат в координаты экрана. А вообще, что мешает при драге прибавлять координаты к позиции шара, чем жестко его двигать в точку курсора?

Comment: Тут принцип такой. Шар двигается, независимо от того, куда нажать на экран. Нажатие в любом месте экрана позиционируется, как нажатие на шар. Это для того, что бы не обязательно было нажимать на сам шар для его движения.

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, по описанию не понятно почему бы просто не перемещать готовый шар на стартовую позицию, зачем удалять старые и плодить новые. Но если прям необходимо пересоздавать, то ранее вам уже описали идею с булевой isDead.

Comment: Дело в том, что я пробовал менять координаты. Но т.к. объект "зажат" нажатием мыши, он не телепортируется на стартовую позицию, пока не отпустишь мышь.

Comment: Как раз isDead тут можно и использовать, просто не считывать мышь, когда шар мертв, а как вернётся на стартовую позицию, или что вы там придумаете, вернуть его к жизни isDead = false.

Comment: Попробовал с булевой _isDead, при одновременном столкновением с тремя коллайдерами всё равно происходит клонирование.
А каким образом образом перестать считывать мышь?